# MongoEngine: How to collect embedded documents from referencing document

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I have a class Post which has a list of embedded document called "comments"
Here all i want to do is to retrieve latest comments for all the posts user posted.

How can i achieve that? My current code, i just loop though the 'Post' class for that user and manually collect "comment". 
But I also want this to be sorted by recently added, so have sort function to loop over manually collected comments and re-sort.

This seems like very inefficient, so asking for advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly if you `$push` onto the list with an update then you will keep the comments in order.
You can use the `$slice` operator to return the last x comments eg:

```
Post.objects(id=xxx).fields(slice__comments=-5)
```

However, the schema may not be efficient especially if you keep growing the number of comments, or comments can be unpublished.  In that case you may want to split comments out into their own Document Model and link the comments to the Post by `id`.  This would be two round trips to the database but offers more flexibility - eg. you could filter on date and published.

Comment: is it possible to lookup post object from comment if i just collect the comment object?